# Dynamic arrays in Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Why does my array length always come out to 0 even though var email is equal to a string.  (I've alerted out var email and the data is there).

```
    var emails = new Array();

    //get all the emails
    $('.emailBox input').each(function (i)
    {
        var email = $(this).val();

        if(email != '')
        {
            emails[email] = email;
            alert(emails.length);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Who downvoted this? It's a perfectly valid question (I upvoted back to zero)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're adding a property to the array.

```
var a = [];
a.foo = 42;
a.length === 0; // true
```

Instead try

`emails.push(email);`

This is the same as `emails[emails.length] = email`

As an aside:

`var emails = new Array();`

Is bad. You should be using `[]` instead of `new Array()` mainly because it's more terse and  readable.

`if (email != '') {`

The above can be replace with `if (email) {` in case jQuery ever returns `undefined` or `null`

To make the entire code more elegant you should use

```
var emails = $('.emailBox input').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).filter(function (k, v) { return v; }).get();
```

Or without jQuery

```
var emails = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".emailBox input"), function (v) {
    return v.value;
}).filter(function (v) { return v; });
```

Although you'll need a QSA shim and a ES5 shim for legacy platform support.

**Edit:**

If you want the array to be unique then reduce it.

```
var arr = arr.reduce(function (memo, val, key, arr) {
  // if the first index of the value is the index then add it.
  // if the first index is different then we already have it.
  if (arr.indexOf(val) === key) {
    memo.push(val);
  }
  return memo;
}, []);
```

Comment: While I agree the OP should be using `[]` instead of `new Array()`, would you say the former is more readable (especially for a beginner)?

Comment: Your jQuery code would return a different set then the OP's code (it doesn't add *falsy* emails), and would also return a jQuery object when the OP wants an array. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AYgBE/).

Comment: @alex I fixed that. I made the poor assumption that `.map` behaves similarly to ES5 rather then doing is this jQuery specific nonsense.

Comment: @Raynos jQuery's `map()` working this way lets you easily modify the jQuery collection. It's slightly hacky to use it to return other data types and then toss a `get()` at the end.

Comment: @alex I don't approve. The API is a mess and non-intuitive, but that's an aside. I guess you would want `[].map.call(jQueryObj, mapper)`

Comment: @alex: I do think it's more readable even for a beginner, specially if they try to pass parameters to the constructor

Comment: @alex not to mention the whole `new Array(5) != [5]` trap (first paramter, if number will set the length)

Answer (score 1):

You could do all of that using a few jQuery methods.

```
var emails = $('.emailBox input')
              .map(function() { return $(this).val() || null; })
              .get();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8ZpA/).

Answer (score -1):

emails[email] = email isn't doing what you want it to do. Try

```
emails.push(email);
```

Comment: Why isn't it? It works fine for me. It may not be what the OP *wants*, but it's perfectly valid.

Comment: If emails was an object, then it would work (as you're setting a key to have a value), but it's an array which has numeric indexes. I don't see what it would do with an email address as an index? (Although you could argue that an Array is an object too :) )

Comment: Store it, then look it up by the same--it's just a property. Arrays are objects--try it.

Comment: @Todd of course an array is an object. Everything is an object (apart from `null` and `undefined`)